# How do I turn off MariaDB GTID to revert back to binlog replication?

Tags: replication, mariadb, gtid

We have found concerns with GTID on MariaDB related to our multi-tenant MyISAM databases. It sounds like there are problems with temporary table replication so we'd like to revert away from GTID. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

On each slave, run this. It'll do it without downtime and very little replication delay.

```
stop slave; change master to master_use_gtid=no; start slave;
```

You can watch `show slave status \G`, specifically "Using_Gtid, "Master_Log_File" and "Read_Master_Log_Pos". Assure the first is "No" and the other two are climbing after this command.